# how to connect to SQL server that works on computer that uses proxy

Tags: sql-server, proxy

My SQL server installed on remote computer, that works via proxy server. I know the external IP address, and local network IP of computer. How can I connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow instructions on MSDN:

[`Connecting to SQL Server Through a Proxy Server`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190801%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

[`How to: Connect to SQL Server Through a Proxy Server (SQL Server Configuration Manager)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179448%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If the computer hosting SQL Server is behind a proxy server, and you have no alternate route to that host other than through that proxy server, you're going to have to determine the process necessary to configure the proxy to allow connections from your box to the SQL server...